# Why cover one's face during shofar?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, tallit-gadol, shofar, face

I noticed two people in the synagogue this Rosh Hashana who, whenever the shofar was sounded, covered their respective faces with their respective tallits. I didn't feel comfortable asking them why. (I was a guest in that synagogue.) Anyone know why one might do such a thing?

Comment: Perhaps they want to concentrate or offer a personal supplication at that time

Comment: Perhaps using their sense of sight distracts them from concentrating on their sense of hearing (like a blind person's having better hearing)

Comment: IIRC, years ago, in the shul I attended when I was a child, covering one's face with the tallit was fairly common. I got two answers. A few said that the sound of the shofar caused them to cry and they did not want others to see them crying. My father, who was deaf, told me that seeing the person blow the shofar would make me go blind (similar to the "superstition" of not looking at the Cohanim when they duchan. In hindsight, I don't know if he may have confused the two concepts.)